# Why background-image's url in css file is not working in chrome, but ok in IE & firefox?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In Css file：

```
body {
    background-image: url('../image/body_bg.png');
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

I'm sure the url path is right.

The "body_bg.png" is displayed in IE & firefox brower,but not in Chrome. My chrome version is 22.0.1229.94

Comment: have you tried to delete cache? hit Ctrl + F5 or right side Ctrl+ Shift + delete

Comment: @AMember That won't work, 'cause Chrome does not understand that command as a 'hard refersh'. It is better to open a incognito window. As posted here: http://superuser.com/questions/220179/how-can-i-do-a-cache-refresh-in-google-chrome

Comment: right side Ctrl+ Shift + delete then clear browsing data

Answer (score 0):

change

```
background-image: url('../image/body_bg.png');
```

to

```
background-image: url('image/body_bg.png');
```

maybe helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete cache by hitting **right side** Ctrl + Shift + Delete then clear browsing data. Then refresh the page.